# capistorano 初回実行時に git archive で失敗する

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

新規サーバーで capistorano をはじめて実行するんですが

```
/usr/bin/env git archive  api | tar -x -C /var/www/api/releases/20210519123116 --strip=1
```

の部分で失敗します

おそらく前回デプロイした内容をアーカイブしようとしてるみたいですが
初回なのに実行されてしまうのは何が悪いのでしょうか

archive  api

の間がスペース２個あいてるのでおそらく前回リビジョン名とかがはいるんだと思うんですが
これがないせいで
`git stderr: fatal: not a valid object name: api`
となってしまいます

Capfile

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Include default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'

# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#   https://github.com/capistrano/passenger
#
# require 'capistrano/rvm'
# require 'capistrano/rbenv'
# require 'capistrano/chruby'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/rails/db'
# require 'capistrano/passenger'
require 'capistrano3/unicorn'

require 'capistrano/git'
require "whenever/capistrano"

class Capistrano::Git
  module SubDirectoryStrategy
    include DefaultStrategy

    def release
      git :archive, fetch(:branch), fetch(:project_root), '| tar -x -C', release_path, "--strip=#{fetch(:project_root).count('/')+1}"
    end
  end
end

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }

require 'capistrano/delayed_job'
```

deploy.rb

```
# config valid for current version and patch releases of Capistrano
lock '3.4.1'

set :application, 'api'
set :repo_url, 'ssh://xxxxxx.git'

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp
set :branch, ENV['BRANCH'] || "master"

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
# set :deploy_to, '/var/www/my_app_name'
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/api'
# set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

set :git_strategy, Capistrano::Git::SubDirectoryStrategy
set :project_root, 'api'

# Default value for :scm is :git
set :scm, :git
# Default value for :format is :pretty
# set :format, :pretty

# Default value for :log_level is :debug
set :log_level, :debug

# Default value for :pty is false
# set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
# set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml')
# set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/secrets.yml')
# set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/master.key')

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')
# set :linked_dirs, (fetch(:linked_dirs) + ['tmp'])

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }
set :default_env, {
  rbenv_root: "/usr/local/rbenv",
  path: "/usr/local/rbenv/shims:/usr/local/rbenv/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin:$PATH"
}

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
set :keep_releases, 5

set :unicorn_rack_env, "none"
set :unicorn_config_path, 'config/unicorn.rb'

# set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"
set :whenever_identifier, ->{ "#{fetch(:application)}_#{fetch(:stage)}" }
# set :whenever_identifier, ->{ "#{fetch(:application)}_#{fetch(:development)}" }
# set :whenever_roles, :batch
# set :whenever_environment, :development
# set :whenever_roles,        ->{ :db }
# set :whenever_command,      ->{ [:bundle, :exec, :whenever] }
# set :whenever_command_environment_variables, ->{ {} }
# set :whenever_identifier,   ->{ fetch :application }
# set :whenever_environment,  ->{ fetch :rails_env, fetch(:stage, "development") }
# set :whenever_variables,    ->{ "environment=#{fetch :whenever_environment}" }
# set :whenever_update_flags, ->{ "--update-crontab #{fetch :whenever_identifier} --set #{fetch :whenever_variables}" }
# set :whenever_clear_flags,  ->{ "--clear-crontab #{fetch :whenever_identifier}" }

SSHKit.config.command_map[:rake] = 'bundle exec rake'

after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'
namespace :deploy do
  task :db_seed do
     on roles(:db) do |host|
       within current_path do
         with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
           execute :rake, 'db:seed_fu'
         end
       end
     end
  end

  task :start do
    invoke 'unicorn:start'
  end
  task :restart do
    invoke 'unicorn:restart'
  end
  task :stop do
    invoke 'unicorn:stop'
  end
  
  desc "Dump the data to db/data.yml"
  task :dump_data_yml do
    on roles(:db) do |host|
      within current_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          execute :rake, 'db:data:dump'
        end
      end
    end
  end
  desc "Load the seed data from db/data.yml"
  task :load_data_yml do
    on roles(:db) do |host|
      within current_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          execute :rake, 'db:load'
        end
      end
    end
  end
  
#  after :restart, :clear_cache do
#    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
#    end
#  end

end
```

Comment: `Capfile`や`config/deploy.rb`の内容を追記していただいてもよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: 追記しました。よろしくお願いします

Comment: Capfile というファイルにも処理が書かれていたんですね… どうも環境変数でブランチを指定するようになっていたようで自己解決しました！　情報ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capfile の中に

```
git :archive, fetch(:branch), fetch(:project_root), '| tar -x -C', release_path, "--strip=#{fetch(:project_root).count('/')+1}"
```

というのがあって

```
set :branch, ENV['BRANCH'] || "master"
```

ここで環境変数からブランチ名をうけとるようになっていたようです
環境変数にブランチをセットしたところこの部分でのエラーは無くなりました